# Why doesn't quill-delta yield the right align attribute?

Tags: reactjs, quill, quill-delta

##### Context

I am working on an editor that uses [quill-react](https://github.com/zenoamaro/react-quill) and [delta](https://github.com/quilljs/delta). I'm using delta because I have functions that directly edit the delta from outside the editor, and it sounded like the right approach.

##### Problem

The delta value doesn't seem to have the right align attribute. For example, I'd expect this:
[image]

to have a delta value of:

```
{"ops":[
{"insert":"center", "attributes":{"align":"center"}},
{"insert":"\nright", "attributes":{"align":"right"}}
]}
```

instead of:

```
{"ops":[
{"insert":"center\nright"},
{"attributes":{"align":"center"},"insert":"\n"}
]}
```

which is very ambiguous: reading this value from outside quill, there's no way I can determine that the word "right" needs to be aligned right.

What am I doing wrong? Am I misunderstanding how quill delta works?

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-kalam-u04hsn?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: You're right, that doesn't make sense. Maybe there's a bug in the lib. Have you tried other versions?

Comment: I did try with a few versions. I ended up raising this here https://github.com/quilljs/delta/issues/83